# How to convert Date Format of NOW() to MM-DD-YYYY in Formula Editor

Tags: datetime, formula-field, date

I have a requirement to convert the DATE FORMAT of NOW() to MM-DD-YYYY in formula editor. By doing using DATETIME.format() i can do it in APEX Classes, but i cannot get the same value in FORMULA EDITOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an idea out on the idea exchange for TIMEVALUE which I recommend voting up [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqVkAAK), but until then it looks like you will need to a timezone offset to get the time as a string.

```
TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW())))+"/" +TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW())))+"/" +TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) & " " &
MID(TEXT(NOW()-tzoffset), 12, 2) & ":" & 
MID(TEXT(NOW()-tzoffset), 15, 2) & ":" &
MID(TEXT(NOW()-tzoffset ), 18, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion !! It worked well .. And i was using EST time values so my TZoffset is 0.166 !! Thanks jjbennett

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MONTH`, `DAY` and `YEAR` [formula functions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US#date_and_time_functinons) to do this as shown below. These functions return an `Integer` so you will need to wrap them in `TEXT()` to convert them to a `String`

```
TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) 
& '-' 
& TEXT(DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))) 
& '-' 
& TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW())))
```

If you use `TODAY()` rather than `NOW()` you don't need to convert from `DateTime` to `Date` and the formula gets a little simplier

```
TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
& '-' 
& TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
& '-' 
& TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Comment: When i use TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))), this does not return TIME values for the DATETIME field. It just gives only Dateformat as i desire. But i need time value.
Something like this , "8-13-2014 19:14:00"

Comment: You should update your question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just after date, you can use TODAY instead of NOW

give this a try and see if it works for you

```
TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()) & '-' & DAY(TODAY()) & '-' & YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Comment: My requirement is to use NOW() a DATETIME datatype. I tried using TODAY(), its suppressing my time values for the same.

Comment: this will return 1-3-2014 rather than 01-03-2014